# Configuring JAXRS to do schema validation for only some service beans

Tags: spring, cxf, jax-rs, xsd-validation

I have a Spring-configured CXF-powered JAX-RS service with two service beans:

```
 <jaxrs:server id="wsServices">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
       <ref bean="a"/>
       <ref bean="b"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:schemaLocations>
        <jaxrs:schemaLocation>
           classpath:/schema/webservices.xsd
        </jaxrs:schemaLocation>
    </jaxrs:schemaLocations>
 </jaxrs:server>

<bean id="a" class="AServiceImpl"/> 
<bean id="b" class="BServiceImpl" />
```

Unfortunately, only one of the two service beans is covered by the XSD file, so that that other one fails at schema validation.

I know how to turn off schema validation altogether, and then both services work fine (but I'd rather continue to have validation where it can be used).

How can I change the configuration to only use schema validation for bean `a`, but not for `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema validation is set at the JAX-RS service level, so you can't do what you want directly (without adding to the schema) but you *can* have multiple `<jaxrs:server>` instances in the same webapp with different paths. That should let you set up what you want without too much trouble. (This is where the more sophisticated configuration approach of CXF comes into its own.)

Comment: That looks doable. However, I would then need to change the path (URL) prefix for one of the services, right?

Comment: "need to change the path": Not necessary. The two jaxrsServers can have overlapping paths (for example beanA the default '/' and beanB the previous one from the class annotation, such as '/serviceB'), and you can compensate for extra segments by stripping them out of the Path annotation on the class. So external URL can stay the same.

Comment: Well, I have four separate “servers” in one application (in my case because I need different type mappings) so this sort of feature is super-useful.